# What Is "\t%.10g\n"

Tags: c, printf, bison

I'm new at Bison, but in C/C++ no and at this time of development and regular expressions i never heard something like this, only the `\n` that's used for a new line,  but i want to know what is the explanation of `\t%.10g`, that in the code is like this:

```
line:     '\n'
        | exp '\n'  { printf ("\t%.10g\n", $1); }
;
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "print a tab character (\t) followed by a floating point number with 10 decimal places, either in scientific or fixed point notation depending on the order of magnitude (%.10g), followed by a newline (\n)".

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`printf` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) to decode the pattern:

> `g`   Use the shorter of `%e` or `%f`
>
> `e`   Scientific notation (mantise/exponent) using e character
>
> `f`   Decimal floating point

Thus, `%.10g` prints a decimal number with ten significant digits.

Comment: Actually, there is a slight difference between %g and [either %e or %f]: the precision specifies the number of significant digits, for [%e or %f] it specifies the number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a regex but a printf format specification : Print a tab character followed by a floating point number with 10 digits behind the decimal point, either %f (floating point notation) way or %e (scientific notatation) way, whichever is shorter, and end with a newline.

```
man printf
```